# Correlated sub selects with COUNT condition from another table

Tags: mysql

I am having a problem with figuring out a MySQL query. The pseudo-code would be like this:
table 1 is users table
table 2 is a posts table, and I need to select only those users, who had minimum 5 posts within the time of 1000-2000 seconds of activity.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE **( COUNT(id) FROM table2 WHERE `user`=user_id.table1 AND `time`> 1000 AND `time`< 2000 ) > 5** AND active.table1 = 1 LIMIT 0,10
```

Answer (score 0):

Every subquery needs it own  `SELECT`

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE (SELECT  COUNT(id) FROM table2 WHERE `user`=table1.user_id AND `time`> 1000 AND `time`< 2000 ) > 5 
AND table1.active = 1 LIMIT 0,10
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this mysql query:

```
SELECT table1.* FROM table1 WHERE table1.active = 1 AND (  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE table2.user = table1.user_id   AND table2.time >= 1000 AND table2.time <= 2000) >= 5;
```

This query returns all rows from table1 where the active column is 1 and the user has posted within the specified time frame. A subquery within the WHERE clause counts the number of posts made by each user. If the number of posts for a given user is greater than or equal to 5, the outer query returns that user's row from table1.